# Java "pool" of longs or Oracle sequence that reuses released values

Tags: java, oracle

Several months ago I implemented a solution to choose unique values from a range between 1 and 65535 (16 bits). This range is used to generate unique Route Targets suffixes, which for this customer massive network (it's a huge ISP) are a very disputed resource, so any released value needs to become immediately available to the end user.

To tackle this requirement I used a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). Allocate a suffix on the RT index with `set` and deallocate a suffix with `clear`. The method [nextClearBit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#nextClearBit%28int%29) can find the next available value. I handle synchronization / concurrency issues manually.

This works pretty well for a small range... The entire index is small (around 10k), it is blazing fast and can be easy serialized and stored in a blob field.

The problem is, some new devices can handle RT suffixes of 32 bits unsigned (range 1 / 4294967296). Which can't be managed with a BitSet (it would, by itself, consume around 600Mb, plus be limited to `int` - 32 bits signed - range). Even with this massive range available, the client still wants to free Route Target suffixes that become available to the end user, mainly because the lowest ones (up to 65535) - which are compatible with old routers - are being heavily disputed.

Before I tell the customer that this is impossible and he will have to conform with my reusable index for lower RTs (up to 65550) and use a database sequence for the other ones (which means that when the user frees a Route Target, it will not become available again), would anyone shed some light?

Maybe some kind soul already implemented a high performance number pool for Java (6 if it matters), or I am missing a killer feature of Oracle database (11R2 if it matters)... Just some wishful thinking :).

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would combine the following:

your current BitSet solution for 1-65535

PLUS

Oracle-based solution with a sequence for 65536 - 4294967296 which wraps around defined as

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MyIDSequence
MINVALUE 65536 
MAXVALUE 4294967296 
START WITH 65536
INCREMENT BY 1
CYCLE
NOCACHE
ORDER;
```

This sequence gives you ordered values in the specified range and allows for reuse of any values but only after the maximum is reached - which should allow enough time for the values being released... if need be you can keep track of values in use in a table and just increment further if the returned value is already in use - all this can be wrapped nicely into a stored procedure for convenience...

Comment: Thanks Yahia, I pretty much think that, unless a miracle happens, my proposed solution will end up looking very much like this. Still, won't cycle just go from 4294967296 back to 65536? I mean, cycle doesn't guarantee uniqueness at all does it?

Comment: Side note: I'm aware that the possibility to ever hit 4 billion route targets isn't there. I'm just curious about cycle behavior.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly yes, `CYCLE` goes back from 4294967296 to 65536... since the above sequence doesn't cache and is ordered you will get unique and consecutive values starting with 65536 till reaching 4294967296 - i.e. all values are exhausted before it wraps back. More Uniqueness is not possible since you set boundaries... if you don't want it to wrap back it will just stop at 4294967296 .

Answer (score 3):

[This project](http://www.iis.uni-stuttgart.de/intset/) may be of some use.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I will take a look at their implementations since it promises good performance with less memory overhead... Still, according to it's [javadocs](http://www.iis.uni-stuttgart.de/intset/doc/intset/TreeIntegerSet.html) looks like `nextClearBit` is restricted to int range.

Comment: yeah, i noticed that it's only ints after i posted it.  however, i left it in the hopes that it may be a useful part of your final solution.